# OGRFeature::DestroyFeature fails

Tags: gdal, ogr, error, c++

I am using OGR to read features from a shape file; when the feature is destroyed I am getting an error 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xffffffffffffffff.

This secton of the code looks pointless but is a simplification of a larger section showing where the error is occuring. I have removed lines of code that could interfere with the objects and I am still getting the same error message.

```
OGRDataSource *hDS;
OGRSFDriver   *Driver;
OGRFeature    *pFeat;

hDS = OGRSFDriverRegistrar::Open(BasePath,FALSE,&Driver);
OGRLayer *Layer = hDS->GetLayerByName(ThisLayerName);
Layer->ResetReading();

while ((pFeat = Layer->GetNextFeature()) != NULL)
{
    // I did intend to do something here
    OGRFeature::DestroyFeature(pFeat); // error occurs here
}
OGRDataSource::DestroyDataSource(hDS);
```

I am using OGR2OGR source as a reference on how to read an OGR datasource. I can see in the reference that each feature returned is destroyed before grabbing a new one until the last feature and the datasource is destroyed thereafter.

I am using GDAL version 1.10 64bit on Windows 7 64bit; I have tried previous versions 1.9.2 and 1.8 and they all return the same error. I am using Visual C++ if that makes any difference.

Comment: I'm at a loss as to why this doesn't work - it looks fine!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, can I say thank you to Frank - for taking the time to read my post, for the fantastic examples and for the post that enabled me to work with GDAL/OGR in Visual Studio. For anyone who is interested, the secret to using GDAL/OGR with Visual Studio is to link to gdal_i.lib in additional dependencies.

This situation seems to have arisen from code that I didn't provide:

```
OGRSpatialReference *OGR_SR = Layer->GetSpatialRef();
OGR_SR->Validate();
char* SR_Text;
OGR_SR->exportToWkt(&SR_Text); 
OGRFree(OGR_SR); // THIS IS THE PROBLEM
```

I was using the spatial reference for the layer and dutifully dismissed it, however after delving into the OGR source codes (ogrfeature.cpp and ogrgeometry.cpp) I could see that the destructor expects to delete the spatial reference... ogrfeature deletes the geometry then the geometry deletes the spatial reference, by removing it myself there was nothing left to remove hence the "access violation".